# Playing YouTube videos in Xamarin

Tags: youtube, xamarin

Is it possible to show and control youtube videos in Xamarin? I found this [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helpe) but not sure how or if it is possible to use it within Xamarin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use that component you can create a Xamarin.iOS binding for it. Or you could use this one: https://github.com/nishanil/YouTubePlayeriOS